# Rank Pandas dataframe by quantile

Tags: python, pandas, percentile

I have a Pandas dataframe in which each column represents a separate property, and each row holds the properties' value on a specific date:

```
import pandas as pd

dfstr = \
'''         AC        BO         C       CCM        CL       CRD        CT        DA        GC        GF
2010-01-19  0.844135 -0.194530 -0.231046  0.245615 -0.581238 -0.593562  0.057288  0.655903  0.823997  0.221920
2010-01-20 -0.204845 -0.225876  0.835611 -0.594950 -0.607364  0.042603  0.639168  0.816524  0.210653  0.237833
2010-01-21  0.824852 -0.216449 -0.220136  0.234343 -0.611756 -0.624060  0.028295  0.622516  0.811741  0.201083'''
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(dfstr), sep='\s+')
```

Using the `rank` method, I can find the percentile rank of each property with respect to a specific date:

```
df.rank(axis=1, pct=True)
```

Output:

```
             AC   BO    C  CCM   CL  CRD   CT   DA   GC   GF
2010-01-19  1.0  0.4  0.3  0.7  0.2  0.1  0.5  0.8  0.9  0.6
2010-01-20  0.4  0.3  1.0  0.2  0.1  0.5  0.8  0.9  0.6  0.7
2010-01-21  1.0  0.4  0.3  0.7  0.2  0.1  0.5  0.8  0.9  0.6
```

What I'd like to get instead is the quantile (eg quartile, quintile, decile, etc) rank of each property. For example, for quintile rank my desired output would be:

```
             AC   BO    C  CCM   CL  CRD   CT   DA   GC   GF
2010-01-19   5    2     2  4     1   1     3    4    5    3
2010-01-20   2    2     5  1     1   3     4    5    3    4
2010-01-21   5    2     2  4     1   1     3    4    5    3
```

I might be missing something, but there doesn't seem to a built-in way to do this kind of quantile ranking with Pandas. What's the simplest way to get my desired output?

Comment: Interested in one-line solution as well. Although, Once you got the rank by `percentile`, getting quartile and so on is just one more line of `map`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Yeah, it's surprisingly tricky. As well, I think there might be some extra edge cases to account for if there is repeated or missing data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Method 1 `mul` & `np.ceil`

You were quite close with the rank. Just multiplying by 5 with `.mul` to get the desired quantile, also rounding up with `np.ceil`:

```
np.ceil(df.rank(axis=1, pct=True).mul(5))
```

---

**`Output`**

```
             AC   BO    C  CCM   CL  CRD   CT   DA   GC   GF
2010-01-19  5.0  2.0  2.0  4.0  1.0  1.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  3.0
2010-01-20  2.0  2.0  5.0  1.0  1.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  3.0  4.0
2010-01-21  5.0  2.0  2.0  4.0  1.0  1.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  3.0
```

If you want integers use `astype`:

```
np.ceil(df.rank(axis=1, pct=True).mul(5)).astype(int)
```

**Or even better**
Since pandas version *0.24.0* we have [nullable integer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) type: `Int64`.
So we can use :

```
np.ceil(df.rank(axis=1, pct=True).mul(5)).astype('Int64')
```

**`Output`**

```
            AC  BO  C  CCM  CL  CRD  CT  DA  GC  GF
2010-01-19   5   2  2    4   1    1   3   4   5   3
2010-01-20   2   2  5    1   1    3   4   5   3   4
2010-01-21   5   2  2    4   1    1   3   4   5   3
```

---

## Method 2 `scipy.stats.percentileofscore`

```
d = df.apply(lambda x: [np.ceil(stats.percentileofscore(x, a, 'rank')*0.05) for a in x], axis=1).values

pd.DataFrame(data=np.concatenate(d).reshape(d.shape[0], len(d[0])), 
             columns=df.columns, 
             dtype='int', 
             index=df.index)
```

**`Output`**

```
            AC  BO  C  CCM  CL  CRD  CT  DA  GC  GF
2010-01-19   5   2  2    4   1    1   3   4   5   3
2010-01-20   2   2  5    1   1    3   4   5   3   4
2010-01-21   5   2  2    4   1    1   3   4   5   3
```

Comment: Ah, nice. I didn't know `np.ceil` would just work on a dataframe without further coercion.

Comment: Yes, since the underlying data of DataFrames are arrays. So you can apply a `numpy` function to them.

Comment: Just for your convenience, I knew I used a method from the `scipy` module for this once. Added another method @tel generate the same output.

Comment: Neat. I knew that dataframes wrap Numpy arrays, but I wonder what trickery the Numpy/Panda devs came up with that allows `np.ceil` to return the desired type (ie `pd.DataFrame`) from `np.ceil` instead of a standard `np.ndarray`.

Comment: Also, one little nitpick: `.astype(int)` doesn't work when you have missing data, since `NaN` is a float. Good news is that so far that's the only edge case failure I found with your solution(s).

Comment: Yes good point about the `NaN`, added a solution with `nullable integer` type. @tel

Answer (score 0):

You can use now [pd.qcut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html)

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 5, labels=False)+1, axis=1)
```

**Completed test case code**

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

dfstr = \
'''         AC        BO         C       CCM        CL       CRD        CT        DA        GC        GF
2010-01-19  0.844135 -0.194530 -0.231046  0.245615 -0.581238 -0.593562  0.057288  0.655903  0.823997  0.221920
2010-01-20 -0.204845 -0.225876  0.835611 -0.594950 -0.607364  0.042603  0.639168  0.816524  0.210653  0.237833
2010-01-21  0.824852 -0.216449 -0.220136  0.234343 -0.611756 -0.624060  0.028295  0.622516  0.811741  0.201083'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(dfstr), sep='\s+')

print('input:','\n',df)
```

**input**

```
                   AC        BO         C       CCM        CL       CRD   
2010-01-19  0.844135 -0.194530 -0.231046  0.245615 -0.581238 -0.593562  \
2010-01-20 -0.204845 -0.225876  0.835611 -0.594950 -0.607364  0.042603   
2010-01-21  0.824852 -0.216449 -0.220136  0.234343 -0.611756 -0.624060   

                  CT        DA        GC        GF  
2010-01-19  0.057288  0.655903  0.823997  0.221920  
2010-01-20  0.639168  0.816524  0.210653  0.237833  
2010-01-21  0.028295  0.622516  0.811741  0.201083
```

```
df_out = df.apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 5, labels=False)+1, axis=1)

print('\n','output:','\n', df_out)
```

**output**

```
             AC  BO  C  CCM  CL  CRD  CT  DA  GC  GF
2010-01-19   5   2  2    4   1    1   3   4   5   3
2010-01-20   2   2  5    1   1    3   4   5   3   4
2010-01-21   5   2  2    4   1    1   3   4   5   3
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please validate your response with input used, as done in accepted answer.