# pandas decile ranks on DataFrame rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
In [207] SUE_df.iloc[45:59,354:359]
Out[207]: 
            PLNTSYS00013 PLNFI0800016 PLODLPL00013 PLTELL000023 PLONE0000014
2009-04-01      -2.7322     0.488461    -0.330779    -0.100912     -2.12907
2009-07-01      4.04982      3.49382    -0.298544    -0.181343      1.89539
2009-10-01     -3.57738     -5.08303      8.24463    -0.103642     0.643103
2010-01-01     -1.42976     0.325262    -0.058854    -0.555572     0.268437
2010-04-01      1.33034    -0.807921     0.191467    -0.311175      2.72122
2010-07-01   -0.0235675    -0.048386     0.258616    -0.171754      -2.8844
2010-10-01     0.660161      4.93671     0.297664     0.751903    -0.851329
2011-01-01      2.03963    -0.650254     0.223173      1.00279     0.114187
2011-04-01      5.06403     0.828365    -0.110528     0.244366      0.11977
2011-07-01     -1.18217      2.29948     0.521475    0.0705636    0.0486713
2011-10-01     0.118289      1.81084     0.198643    -0.768194    -0.833647
2012-01-01     0.148177   -0.0794947    0.0713122     -1.50967    -0.168698
2012-04-01     0.641605    -0.157657     0.036897      1.21578     -1.03026
2012-07-01      0.76635     -1.55429    -0.103827     0.217835     0.109092
```

I want to get a df with decile ranks of the `SUE_df`, I wrote my own method to do it, but I keep thinking there has to be an easier way to do it. I am using `'.qcut(df,10, labels=False)` but it works only with Series not with DataFrame, so I need to iterate over the the rows and then insert them to a new df, its not very complicated, but takes a while.

I am looking to get a result like this:

```
for a in SUE_df.iloc[45:59,354:359].index:
    SUE2.loc[a] = pd.qcut(SUE_df.iloc[45:59,354:359].loc[a], 5,labels=False ) + 1  

Out[212]: 
            PLNTSYS00013  PLNFI0800016  PLODLPL00013  PLTELL000023  PLONE0000014
2009-04-01             1             5             3             4             2
2009-07-01             5             4             1             2             3
2009-10-01             2             1             5             3             4
2010-01-01             1             5             3             2             4
2010-04-01             4             1             3             2             5
2010-07-01             4             3             5             2             1
2010-10-01             3             5             2             4             1
2011-01-01             5             1             3             4             2
2011-04-01             5             4             1             3             2
2011-07-01             1             5             4             3             2
2011-10-01             3             5             4             2             1
2012-01-01             5             3             4             1             2
2012-04-01             4             2             3             5             1
2012-07-01             5             1             2             4             3
```

Is there any DataFrame method that does it rowwise for the whole df?

Comment: not sure only thing comes to my mind is `df.apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 5,labels=False)).add(1)` but its again it is as efficient as your already existing method

Comment: @anky_91 Actually your solution is more efficient. On my machine, is at least a factor 2 faster than OP current method.

Comment: for row-wise use `axis=1`: `df.apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 5,labels=False),axis=1).add(1)`

Comment: with the example, maybe using `rank` would do the same `df.rank (axis=1)`, but for the complete data, which seems to have a lot of columns, maybe `df.rank(axis=1)*10//df.shape[1]` or something like that to rescale the ranking?

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56332572/rank-pandas-dataframe-by-quantile#comment99271903_56332572)

Comment: Thanks guys for help